# What are the effects of increased mass on persons traveling at near light speed?

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, mass, time

It's been a long time since I studied physics (and then only *very* superficially), so please bear with my gross naivete. This question's been running around in my head for about two weeks now, and I need a real physicist to set me straight.

Provided that the following are all valid:

- Mass increases with velocity.
- Mass generates a gravitational force.
- As mass increases, so does its gravitational force.
- As an object accelerates, so does its gravitational force, due to the increase in its mass.
- <strike>Time passes faster as the gravitational force increases.</strike>

Wouldn’t time for a person traveling near the speed of light seem to pass *faster*, rather than *slower* than that of a person on Earth? **Edit: No. Time passes slower in a larger gravity well.** (Thanks, Jim.)

Also, wouldn’t such an individual exert a gravitational pull on objects he or she passed, dragging them along behind him or her to their destination (provided they achieved sufficient mass)?

I'm assuming, at this point, that one or more of my assumptions are wildly inaccurate. Please, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Time passes slower in a larger gravity well.

Comment: This set of question is one of the best reasons to *stop teaching "relativistic mass", already*. They are also several times duplicated, thought I don't recall what search will turn up the links and I have to go teach class soon.

Comment: @dmckee, I saw (on Wikipedia, of all places) that Einstein, himself, didn't agree with the notion of "relativistic mass." When I was in High School (about 25 years ago), relativistic mass was what they taught. Most of the stuff I see around still teaches it. Has the thinking changed on the matter?

Comment: @Jim, So, that answers the question about the effects on time quite handily. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeHofer $E^2=m_0^2c^4+p^2c^2$ The relativistic mass is what you get when you let all of that be expressed as $E=mc^2$. The rest mass doesn't change, but the momentum does. However, this is only a simplification used to allow you to express momentum in terms of velocity. It does not mean the mass of the object actually increases, just that the mass in its mass-energy equivalency does. Gravitational mass is not the same as relativistic mass. Gravity depends more on the rest mass

Comment: So, then, gravity around the traveler would remain constant, regardless of velocity. And the only thing affecting perception of time would be Earth's gravity well, which is far removed from the traveler and not "slowing time down" for him.

Comment: Earth, the Sun, anything nearby. But time dilation happens due to velocity *and* gravity.

Comment: Professional physics mostly moved away from that phrasing in the 70s and 80s. You still see treatments like that in pop-sci sources and for primary/secondary school. Much to the annoyance of many pros.

Comment: @Jim, AHA! I didn't know that velocity had an effect on time dilation! That clears things up immensely. It certainly explains why time "speeds up" for the traveler, but not for Earth-bound observers. Thanks so much!

Comment: @dmckee, Despite my (glaringly obvious) lack of knowledge, I'm all for getting better teaching tools (books, media, and educators) into our schools, and investing more in science and math in schools. Our current educational state is absolutely deplorable.

Comment: @MikeHofer Just to clarify, you knew that gravity affected time, but not velocity? Well that's a first, usually it's the other way around. But yeah, clocks are observed running slower either at high velocities or deeper in a gravity well

Comment: @Jim, Like I said, it's been a long time, and that's why I'm here. I needed to have this kind of stuff clarified/cleaned up/corrected. I'd rather fill in gaps in knowledge, rather than run around like an idiot *thinking* I know something, when I've clearly got it wrong.

Comment: @MikeHofer I like your attitude! I wish more people were like that

Answer (score 2):

Consider this: the space traveler is flying at near light speed relative to you. But *for him* you are flying at near light speed, just in opposite direction. So he must think then that you have to experience all the "effects of the increased mass", mustn't he?

The answer is in the fact that the very basis of Special Relativity is the postulate of equivalence of all moving reference frames. Any unusual effect perceived by someone traveling at near light speed will clearly contradict the very first postulate of Special Relativity.